# Error when installing chromium on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: command-line, chromium

```
    sudo apt-get install chromium-browser

[sudo] password for leo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/48.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 164 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 184344 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the chromium snap
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "chromium" (1466) from channel "stable" (unexpected EOF)
- Download snap "gnome-3-28-1804" (145) from channel "stable" (unexpected EOF)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new chromium-browser package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

what do i do?

Comment: Have you tried installing it [via PPA](https://fosspost.org/chromium-deb-package-ubuntu-20-04/)? That might work better for you, unless you insist on it being a snap.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: @David sorry it's 20.10

Comment: @KGIII what is the difference between snap and PPA?

Comment: PPA is the more traditional way, using apt as the package manager. Then, there are newer methods to install software - each with slight differences. [This link](https://linuxhint.com/snap_vs_flatpak_vs_appimage/) describes a few of the alternatives. Snap is native in Ubuntu by default.

Answer (score 1):

try to install Chromium via flatpack:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

After this step ^ , may be you need to reboot your system

```
flatpak install flathub org.chromium.Chromium
flatpak run org.chromium.Chromium
```

P.S. also, this is the answer to your question about differences between ppa and snap :

> Snaps are intended to be an upgrade over PPAs, which were themselves intended to be an upgrade over adding random repositories to your sources.list. PPAs are not very discoverable, and could adversely affect the rest of your system; snaps, being sandboxed and being listed in the default package manager, improve on those aspects. That sandboxing creates some other issues, like the slow startup time and needing to set permissions for access into and out of the sandbox, compared to traditional packages.

Comment: sorry didn't put an update earlier, i just restarted the pc and it was installed.